# route maps generator in php

Tags: javascript, php

- How to generate the route map in **Google Maps** from one point to another ?

Including all the points between them when the latitude and longitude are taken from the table using **PHP** and **Javascript**.

Comment: Please let us know what you've researched, and what you've already tried. Also, please do a little bit more to explain your desired input/output. Do you want to just extract the route that Google Maps produces? Or do you want to generate your own route? Is the desired output just a list of latitude and longitude points? If so, only for turns? Or a series of points that traces the entire route?

Comment: i just tried but i didn't get  any thing so posted question...  i just need a route map of series latitude and longitude points for the entire route

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Waypoints in directions</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var waypts = [];
  var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected == true) {
      waypts.push({
          location:checkboxArray[i].value,
          stopover:true});
    }
  }

  var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
      }
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
    <div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
    <div style="margin:20px;border-width:2px;">
    <b>Start:</b>
    <select id="start">
      <option value="Halifax, NS">Halifax, NS</option>
      <option value="Boston, MA">Boston, MA</option>
      <option value="New York, NY">New York, NY</option>
      <option value="Miami, FL">Miami, FL</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <b>Waypoints:</b> <br>
    <i>(Ctrl-Click for multiple selection)</i> <br>
    <select multiple id="waypoints">
      <option value="montreal, quebec">Montreal, QBC</option>
      <option value="toronto, ont">Toronto, ONT</option>
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="winnipeg, mb">Winnipeg</option>
      <option value="fargo, nd">Fargo</option>
      <option value="calgary, ab">Calgary</option>
      <option value="spokane, wa">Spokane</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <b>End:</b>
    <select id="end">
      <option value="Vancouver, BC">Vancouver, BC</option>
      <option value="Seattle, WA">Seattle, WA</option>
      <option value="San Francisco, CA">San Francisco, CA</option>
      <option value="Los Angeles, CA">Los Angeles, CA</option>
    </select>
    <br>
      <input type="submit" onclick="calcRoute();">
    </div>
    <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ref:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

Comment: thanks for your answer that was very useful.i need one more help that is regarding playback option from the starting point to the ending point..

Comment: you want static start and end point?

Comment: No its random.. from the database we have to fetch the starting point and ending point

Comment: ok.you can set dynamically set values following code:

Comment: var start ='Halifax, NS';
  var end = 'Vancouver, BC';

Comment: did you get this point  ?.....

Comment: Inside "function calcRoute() {}"

Comment: var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value; i can set like this code

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: no error its working fine

Comment: http://www.kmcgraphics.com/google/    check this link in that page when i click the start the object moves automatically to the ending point ...

Comment: i need a code for live object moving ....between the starting point and ending point

Comment: i want to see vehicle moving live on google maps from starting point to ending point